# Iterative technique to solving matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have a numerical methods problem that has me a bit stumped.  To be honest, I'm just not sure where to  start on this problem, so I would appreciate some help interpreting the question, and from there I should be able to find my way with solving the matrix:

\begin{array}{cccc|c}
0.06 & 0.08 & 0.07 & 0.08 & 0.29 \\
0.08 & 0.20 & 0.09 & 0.07 & 0.29 \\
0.07 & 0.09 & 0.20 & 0.10 & 0.29 \\
0.06 & 0.08 & 0.10 & 0.20 & 0.29 \end{array}

Suppose we are to solve the equation

$$Ax = b$$

We solve this by

$$x = \frac{1}{A}b = \frac{1}{\omega A} * \omega b = 1/(1-r) \omega b$$

where $\omega \neq 0$ is some real number chosen to weigh the problem appropriately, and $r = 1 - \omega A$.  Now suppose that w was chosen such that $|r| < 1$ and $A \neq 0$.  Then the following geometric expansion holds:

$$\frac{1}{1-r} = 1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + ... $$

This gives the approximate solution to our problem as

$$
\begin{align}
x & \approx [ 1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + ... + r^k ] \omega b \\
& = \omega b + [ r + r^2 + r^3 + ... + r^k ] \omega b \\
& = \omega b + r [ 1 + r + r^2 + ... + r^k-1 ] \omega b \\
\end{align}
$$

This suggests an iterative approach to solving the system Ax = b.  Let x^(0) = wb be the initial

estimate of the solution, then for the kth iteate we have

$$\begin{align}
x(k) & = \omega b + rx^{(k-1)} \\
& = \omega b + (1 - \omega A)x^{(k-1)} \\
\end{align}$$

If $|r| < 1$, then the iterate $x^{(k)}$ is guaranteed to converge to the true solution.
For some matrix $M$ and some scaling factor w, we obtain the following algorithm:

$$ Mx^{(k)} = \omega b + (M - \omega A) x^{(k-1)} $$

Let $A$ be the matrix above and $ \omega = 1 $.  Solve the system by choosing $M$ to be the matrix consisting of the diagonal of $A$.

My question is, how do I apply the iteration to solve the given matrix?  I'm quite new to iterative techniques in solving matrices, so any insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Before we start, do you understand what all the notation means? For example, what does $|r|$ mean for $r$ a matrix? I should also point out that it is non-standard to use fractions to indicate matrix inverses. So you should not do $1/A$, but rather $A^{-1}$.

Comment: This is weighted Jacobi iteration, but your exact question is not clear. This might help in the meantime: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method